# SignalR behind web proxy for portable class library

Tags: c#, signalr, portable-class-library, webproxy

I am developing a PCL Library that will be used for Xamarin/iOS to access a SignalR backend. Everything worked fine, until I tried to run the app behind a web proxy, which resulted in "Connection refused" exceptions.

Normally, SignalR client libraries allow me to specify the Web Proxy using `HubConnection.Proxy`, however the Portable version lacks this property.

What is the correct way to specify the web proxy for the hubConnection, so that it can connect properly?